# Get all values available in a Combobox in Vaadin

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

There are several comboboxes in my code which I fill with values via

```
  List<String> items = ...
  combobox.setItems(items);
```

but I don't really know how to get ***all*** these items out of it. In the previous case, of course, it is easy because the `items` object still exists. But in more complex cases, e.g. debugging, I'd like to have something like

```
  List<String> items = combobox.getItems();
```

but I couldn't find any suggestion how to do it. Even official Vaadin documentation doesn't say a word about it: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples

I know there might be some more complex cases when using  `comboBox.setDataProvider(service::fetch, service::count);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `combobox.setItems(items);` then `ComboBox` will automatically create a `ListDataProvider` out of those items, which means that you could the following

```
ListDataProvider dataProvider = (ListDataProvider) comboBox.getDataProvider();
allItems = dataProvider.getItems();
```